# jquery intercept

Tags: jquery

In another question's discussion, I became aware of intercepting clicks and updating area without refreshing the whole page. Problem is, the following code seems correct to me and I dont receive any errors but data taken from another page is not displayed at all. 
Please advise.

main page

```
    $('ul.thumbs li.pagination a').live('click', function() { 
        var pageNumber = parseInt($(this).text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));

     $(function ViewImages() {
      $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "/FLPM/cp/images.cs.asp?Process=ViewImages&PAGEID=" + pageNumber,
       success: function(data) {
        $("#ViewImages").html(data);
       },
       error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $("#ViewImages").html('.');
       }
      });
     });

        return false;
    });

<div id="ViewImages">                                       
</div>
```

page where data lays

```
      <ul class="thumbs">

        <li>
         <a href="#" class="thumb"><img src="/FLPM/media/news/images/5P2B4K5M_sm.jpg" alt="Forest Flowers" class="floatLeft" /></a>
            <br />
          <a href="?Process=DeleteImage&IMAGEID=21" class="thumb"><span class="floatLeft">DELETE</span></a>
  </li>

        <li>

         <a href="#" class="thumb"><img src="/FLPM/media/news/images/6Z3L5U6W_sm.jpg" alt="Forest" class="floatLeft" /></a>
            <br />
          <a href="?Process=DeleteImage&IMAGEID=20" class="thumb"><span class="floatLeft">DELETE</span></a>
  </li>

        <li>
         <a href="#" class="thumb"><img src="/FLPM/media/news/images/8O5A7J8M_sm.jpg" alt="Dock" class="floatLeft" /></a>
            <br />
          <a href="?Process=DeleteImage&IMAGEID=19" class="thumb"><span class="floatLeft">DELETE</span></a>

  </li>

        <li>
         <a href="#" class="thumb"><img src="/FLPM/media/news/images/9Q6B3Q4S_sm.jpg" alt="Desert Landscape" class="floatLeft" /></a>
            <br />
          <a href="?Process=DeleteImage&IMAGEID=18" class="thumb"><span class="floatLeft">DELETE</span></a>
  </li>

        <li>

         <a href="#" class="thumb"><img src="/FLPM/media/news/images/5B2N4W5Z_sm.jpg" alt="Creek" class="floatLeft" /></a>
            <br />
          <a href="?Process=DeleteImage&IMAGEID=17" class="thumb"><span class="floatLeft">DELETE</span></a>
  </li>

        <li class="pagination">1.&nbsp;</li>

        <li class="pagination"><a href="2">2.</a>&nbsp;</li>

 </ul>
```

Comment: The HTML doesn't have an element with the id "ViewImages" and has machine detectable errors: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: It actually does. I did not think it was necessary to add it here. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I might be missing something, but where are you invoking the ViewImages function? Or why is the method wrapped in $() ?

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674991/intercept-click-event-on-a-button-ask-for-confirmation-then-proceed/4675010#4675010

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your function definition is unnecessary. Maybe this'll work better:

```
$('ul.thumbs li.pagination a').live('click', function() { 
   var pageNumber = parseInt($(this).text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));

   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/FLPM/cp/images.cs.asp?Process=ViewImages&PAGEID=" + pageNumber,
      success: function(data) {
         $("#ViewImages").html(data);
      },
      error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         $("#ViewImages").html('.');
      }
   });

   return false;
});
```

Comment: I dont really see a difference here. Well, it neither gave an error nor worked. http://www.refinethetaste.com/FLPM/cp/?Section=news&Process=AddNews

Answer (score 0):

Your **pagination** class is missing from the HTML you provided.  $('ul.thumbs li.**pagination** a')

Comment: how about this `<li class="pagination"><a href="2">2.</a>&nbsp;</li>`