# Intercept click event on a button, ask for confirmation, then proceed

Tags: jquery

Based on a variable `SomeCondition`, I need to intercept a click event on a button, and ask for confirmation, if they say ok, proceed, otherwise ignore click.

So something like:

```
if(SomeCondition) {

// disable click on button

var isOk = window.confirm("Are you sure?");

if(isOk) {
        $("#button1").click();
}

}
```

Note: button1 has already been wired up with a click event via javascript from an external .js file that I can't change.

I don't know what the click event was bound too, so I have to disable the click if SomeCondition is true, then ask for confirmation, then continue with the click.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Process isOK your window.confirm within the function of the button

```
$('#button1').click(function(){ 
   if(window.confirm("Are you sure?"))
     alert('Your action here');
});
```

The issue you're going to have is the click has already happened when you trigger your "Are You Sure"  Calling preventDefault doesn't stop the execution of the original click if it's the one that launched your original window.confirm.

Bit of a chicken/egg problem.

Edit: after reading your edited question:

```
    var myClick = null;

    //get a list of jQuery handlers bound to the click event
    var jQueryHandlers = $('#button1').data('events').click;

    //grab the first jquery function bound to this event
    $.each(jQueryHandlers,function(i,f) {
       myClick = f.handler; 
       return false; 
    });

    //unbind the original
    $('#button1').unbind('click');

    //bind the modified one
    $('#button1').click(function(){
        if(window.confirm("Are You Sure?")){
            myClick();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This was what I was writing up.  +1

Comment: @Blankman sorry bad habit (if there is more than one matching element then you can get the first one by simply referring to the first element in the jQuery object array)

Comment: That can happen if the original click event is not just a single native dom handler.  I'll edit my answer to show how to copy a jQuery click handler.

Comment: what do you mean by not a single native dom handler? thanks for this info!

Comment: So it's a little weird @Blankman.  Consider document.getElementById('#button1').onclick = function(){alert('w00t');};  When you later try to access the onclick property and log it to the console you'll see that it is a function / handler.  However if the original setter is jQuery $('#button1').bind and you attempt the same thing you'll see that the onclick property is not a function but rather an array.  So you need to loop through the jQuery event bindings for that element.  (hope that helps).  I by no means are an expert on the difference however this is perceived behavior etc.

Comment: +1 for Brilliant! I wonder if there's any easier way to do all that, tho. by the way, instead of `return false` [looks like](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788463/how-can-i-intercept-a-link-with-jquery-when-using-a-ajax-call/788501#788501) it's better to use `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: For info ... there is a parenthesis missing on line 'if(window.confirm("Are You Sure?"){' -> 'if(window.confirm("Are You Sure?")){'. But I don't have Edit privilege...

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery to prevent default you just `return false`:

```
$("#button1").click(function () {
    //do your thing
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Eh...  not really.  This will prevent bubbling.

Comment: @Stephen http://api.jquery.com/submit/ "we can cancel the submit action by calling .preventDefault() on the event object or by returning false from our handler"

Comment: @Stephen `return false;` actually does preventDefault and stopPropagation

Answer (score 2):

To anyone who is looking for a simple solution (not particular to the special condition mentioned here)

Just add this attribute to the button:

```
.... , onclick = "return confirm('are you sure?')"
```

When the confirmation box returns a false, the click event gets cancelled.
Note: The onclick handler explicitly mentioned inline will override any other bindings.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get any of the answers above to work using jquery 1.9.1

here is what worked for a previously set `click` event

```
var elem = $('#button1');
var oldClick = $._data(elem[0], 'events').click[0].handler;
elem.off('click');

// Pass the original event object.
elem.click(function(e){
  if(window.confirm("Are You Sure?")){
    oldClick(e);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

very similar to Jason Benson's answer above